# RecipeId is not defined

Tags: javascript

```js
const createRecipe = () => {
    const recipeId = uuidv4()

    const recipe = {
        id: recipeId,
        title: '',
        body: '',
        ingredients: [] 
    }
    recipes.push(recipe)
    saveRecipe()
    return recipeId
}

console.log(recipeId)
```

I imported uuidv4 library, but I am getting a reference error by trying to log recipeId to the console. Because of this function, all my application doesn't work. Could you please explain me, what am I doing wrong here? Sorry, if a question is silly, but I am stuck with it! Thanks!

Comment: Your variable `recipeId` is only available inside the `createRecipe` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, on your code, `recipeId` is defined inside the arrow function and you have called that outside of the function.

I think the purpose you needed is to get the new id of the created recipe.

So I think this code `console.log(recipeId)` should be replaced with `console.log(createRecipe())` then you will get the newly created recipeId.

Answer (score 0):

recipeId is only defined within the scope of the createRecipe function, so it is not available globally. You should instead move console.log(recipeId) into the createRecipe function